Problem calculating correct position in Flame Game Component Render() override
I have a custom flame game TextComponent and I want to draw extra stuff in the render override. I’m using 4 different formulas to calculate the position but each try is wrong. None of these formulas calculates a circle position that stays glued to the moving text. Instead they move as if some scale factor was involved. Any ideas what I’m doing wrong?
void render(Canvas canvas) {
   super.render(canvas);

   canvas.drawCircle(Offset(position.x, position.y), 10, redPaint);

   Vector2 pos = position / scale.x;
   Component? parent = this.parent;
   while (parent != null) {
       if (parent is PositionComponent) {
           pos -= parent.position / parent.scale.x;
       }
       parent = parent.parent;
   }

   canvas.drawCircle(Offset(pos.x, pos.y), 10, yellowPaint);

   canvas.drawCircle(
       Offset(absolutePosition.x / absoluteScale.x, absolutePosition.y / absoluteScale.y),
       10,
       bluePaint);

   canvas.drawCircle(Offset(position.x / scale.x, position.y / scale.y), 10, greenPaint);
}


Ah - looks like the transformation is set already when render() is called so drawing to position (0,0) inside the render() override will draw to the top/left corner of the textComponent, moving with it: canvas.drawCircle(Offset.zero, 10, redPaint);
